# Automatically Start/Stop EC2, Confused with Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am looking to automatically schedule the starting and stopping of my EC2 instance, but I'm having trouble with almost all of the guides that are out there. I'm new to AWS and amazon seems to have recently changed their gui somewhat, which has made the guides a little more confusing for me.

I have been trying to use [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/ec2-scheduler/latest/ec2-scheduler.pdf) guide, but I get lost at "Step 2: Tag Your Amazon EC2 Instances." Can anyone decipher this for me? I believe that I have done everything correctly up to that point.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's not clear what part of this has you confused.  You specified a custom tag name in step 1.  Step 2 is telling you to apply that tag with a value of "true" or "default" to the instances you want the scheduler to be able to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

[Tagging your Amazon EC2 Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html)

Comment: I think I understand pretty well how the tags work. But what do they do in the second part of that guide? Something about the ec2 server having the same tag as the stack.